# How to wirte a REST URL in Firefox search engine plugin

Tags: xml, firefox, search-engine

I tried to write a search engine plugin for Firefox and when writing a template like http:www.mytemplate.com/search?q=XXXX, I use

```
  <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.mytemplate.com/search">
    <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
  </Url>
```

This works fine.

But what if I need `http:www.mytemplate.com/search/q/XXXX` How should I construct the template ?

I tried

```
  <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.mytemplate.com/search/q/{searchTerms}">
  </Url>
```

But it does not work to collect the searchTerms in the URL when I search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the answer by myself.

It seems firefox does not load the file again though I restart, so I delete the original one and copy another one into a new name, now it works

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.mytemplate.com/search/q/{searchTerms}">
</Url>
```